# SWT and Java WebStart on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: java, cocoa, swt, java-web-start

I am using the most stable SWT Cocoa downloads for Mac OS X and and launching my app via Java WebStart. All jnilib files are within my app jar on its root. The app downloads, verifies, but I cannot get any buttons to respond. I can enter data into all my UI components. My VM arguements are "-d32" and "-XstartOnFirstThread".

The app works fine as a stand alone app bundle (running in 32-bit mode), and works fine running out of Eclipse on the same machine.

Is there a known issue with Cocoa SWT (swt-3.5-cocoa-macosx.zip) and WebStart on Mac? The JNLP is pretty standard, so maybe there is a setting that needs to be declared?

Comment: Do you have a link to the MouseUp/MouseDown bug you've mentioned is fixed in the later versions of SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in swt cocoa 3.6 M2 for mac osx. The issue was MouseUp and MouseDown events did not fire. If using a earlier version than this one, SWT.Selection worked ok for buttons.

Comment: Do you have a link to the MouseUp/MouseDown bug you've mentioned is fixed in the later versions of SWT?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug in SWT on OS X as of SWT 3.0: [Bug 63306](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63306).

Comment: I have seen this bug posted as well, but wasnt sure if it applied to me. I got that invalid thread access a while ago, but adding in the "-XstartOnFirstThread" corrected it. My app launches via JWS, but buttons do not respond to clicks. Makes me think its a new issue.